# How do I protect a path in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I followed [this page](https://blog.netcetera.com/how-to-create-guarded-routes-for-your-react-app-d2fe7c7b6122) to create a React application and it worked fine.

However, when I added the following link:

```
 <li>
     <Link to='/protected/gg'>
         Link to Protected Page GG
     </Link>
 </li>
```

The word "GG" is shown without login when I browse the path `/protected/gg`.

It seems that the `GuardedRoute` can protect `/protected` path only.

So, is it possible to protect everything under `/protected` folder?

If so, would you tell me how to do so? Or give me a keyword so that I can google the solution.

[Stackblitz of my work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nxxvkf)

Comment: You probably are aware already, but you can't 100% protect a route with react, since any user can still see the source code and thus find the content of the page.

Comment: Have you checked the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) for an auth-flow? What is the issue? Your `GuardedRoute` component seems to work. Are you *really* asking how to "protect" nested routes? Because putting "/protected/gg" on a `GuardedRoute` should be simple enough. Check [Nesting Routes](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) and combine the two patterns.

Comment: Yes, I want to protect the "protect" nested route.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm stating the obvious and it's not what you're after, but have you tried just changing `<Route exact path='/protected/gg' component={GG}/>` to `<GuardedRoute exact path='/protected/gg' component={GG} auth={isAutheticated}/>`?

Comment: I have tried it. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to other answer, but IMO a little simpler.

While you could just define a flat list of routes, some guarded and some not, you could create "walled guardens" (*see what I did there*).

Modify your `GuardedRoute` to conditionally render a `Route` or `Redirect`, passing all the other props through.

```
const GuardedRoute = ({ auth, ...rest }) => {
  return auth ? <Route {...rest} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
};
```

Then simply make a "guarded" section in your router. Remember that order of routes within a `Switch` component matter, so order *more specific* paths before *less specific paths.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <GuardedRoute path="/protected" auth={isAutheticated}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/protected/gg" component={GG} />
      <Route path="/protected" component={Protected} />
    </Switch>
  </GuardedRoute>
  <Route path="/unprotected" component={Unprotected} />
</Switch>
```

I typically use codesandbox, but let me know if this forked stackblitz fails to load.

https://react-mjyp8g.stackblitz.io

Comment: Your solution works. It is my stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-camdbw

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component to check the authentication of your protected routes and pass your component to it to check for the logged in or any other authorization state

App js will have only app route

```
import React from 'react';
import AppRoute from './components/Routes/appRoute'
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <AppRoute></AppRoute>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Below is the main Application route

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";
import Public from "Public";
import Private from "Private";
const AppRoute = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/public" exact component={Public}></Route>
      <ProtectedRoute
        exact
        path="/private"
        component={Private}
      ></ProtectedRoute>
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default AppRoute;
```

Auth checking component to check for login state

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: true,
  };
  
  componentDidMount (){
//write code to check auth and update state to true or false 
  }

  render() {
    const { exact, path, component } = this.props;
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <>
//you can also change path as path={`/private/${path}`}
            <Route path={path} component={component} exact={exact} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/public" }} />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ProtectedRoute;
```